# How to count number of objects in array by property?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple "top 3" of the users that have the most messages.
So far I was able to group the user and messages inside an array of objects

```js
let data = [ { message: 'fsaasfafs', user: 'John' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'John' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'John' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Smith' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Samantha' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Luis' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Samantha' }]

console.log(data);
```

In this case, the top 3 would be **John - 3 ; Samantha - 2; Smith or Luis (does not matter) - 1**
I would like a map with the user as key and the amount of messages.

Any help please?

Comment: Please post what you have tried to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @jonas - How does [*sorting*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects-by-property) answer this question? (I've added a dupe that I think does, I'm just curious about the one you picked.)

Comment: @t.j. well, I was just about to do the same (adding a few more duplicates), but you two were faster :)

Comment: `let statsMap = {};
        data.forEach(message => {
            if(statsMap.hasProperty(message.user)) {

            }
            else {
                statsMap[message.user] = 
            }
        });`

i got stuck

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let data = [ { message: 'fsaasfafs', user: 'John' },
      { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'John' },
      { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'John' },
      { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Smith' },
      { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Samantha' },
      { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Luis' },
      { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Samantha' }];
      
    let topM = Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, c) => { acc[c.user] = (acc[c.user] || 0 ) + 1; return acc;},{})).sort(function (a, b) { return b[1] - a[1];}).slice(0, 3);
    console.log(topM);
```

Hope This helps you !

Answer (score 0):

You could do like get count of each user message

1. Then you could count the each user messages using `Array#reduce` with `Array#filter`*(this will match the user count in array for each user)*

```js
let data = [ { message: 'fsaasfafs', user: 'John' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'John' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'John' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Smith' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Samantha' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Luis' },
  { message: 'asgsgaasgags', user: 'Samantha' }]
  
 let user_list = data.reduce((a,b,c,d)=>{
   if(Object.keys(a).indexOf(b.user) == -1){
    a[b.user] = d.filter(i=>i.user == b.user).length
   }
   return a
 },{})
 
 console.log(user_list)
```

Comment: please explain :/

Comment: This is not very efficient. Not only does it involve three iterations (`map`, `filter`, and `reduce`) when it could be done in one, it also has a nested iteration happening with  `indexOf`, which gives it a *O(n²)* time complexity. On top of that, this question has been asked before and has useful answers already.

Comment: @trincot i just update method with single parent loop